# how to run ruby scripts at http://localhost:3000/ , NOT RUBY ON RAILS

Tags: ruby

I started to learn ruby programming language,
 i want to output my ruby scripts in my browser, i'm not talkin about ruby-on-rails framework,
 i just need to output only and only ruby scripts to my browser, i followed this tutorial
 `http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=34`
 but through this tutorial i can output ruby-on-rails scripts to my browser,
 but this is not what i need,
 i just need to output ruby script, NOT RAILS. do you know a way to accomplish this task? thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing a simple webserver in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417078/writing-a-simple-webserver-in-ruby)

Comment: "Running an application on HTTP" and "writing a web server" are two different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind a web server to port 3000, then either use [CGI](http://coolnamehere.com/geekery/ruby/web/cgi.html) or use something such as [Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) to serve a [Rack](http://rack.rubyforge.org/) application.

Comment: i tried CGI method, i'm getting this error `Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message: 
couldn't create child process: 720002: hello1.cgi

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500

localhost
15-09-2011 16:03:32
Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1`

Comment: okay fine , now i'm getting this error `Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message: 
Premature end of script headers: hello.cgi

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.`

Comment: I'm running into this too. I could clearly understand the guide. Here I have two questions, how to bind web server to port 3000? How to use CGI?

Comment: Both are already answered. The first on SF, the other on this site.